# what are all steps to find catchment area for weir by ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

What are the all steps to find catchment area for weir on intermittent stream by ArcMap?

I have coordinates and elevation of that point.
 I am in search of that but I did not find it clearly. i have to find I have not total command on ArcMap so give me detailed answer.

Comment: Do you have spatial analysts extention?

Comment: What data do you have? An elevation model, streams and creeks? A detailed answer will require some more details from you in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Hydrology Toolset within Spatial Analyst.  A good overview of using the toolset can be [found here](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~vmerwade/education/hydrology.pdf).

ArcCatalog> ArcToolbox - Spatial Analyst - Hydrology tools

1. Basin Tool
2. Flow Accumulation Tool
3. Watershed Tool

if you don't have the Spatial Analyst extension enabled in Esri, I recommend using Global Mapper which has a [Watershed Delineation toolset](http://www.globalmapperforum.com/features/watershed-delineation-tool/) that will complete your task.  Page 181 of the [Global Mapper v14 Help Guide](http://globalmapper.com/helpv14/GlobalMapperHelp.pdf) starts the discussion.

You will need a terrain grid to start with, which covers your chosen project area. These tools do not function on vector data, the input terrain must be gridded with Z elevation.

Answer (score -1):

My old landscape dynamics lecturer has some good material:

http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/homes/mattal/Topo1.pdf

Have a look at **Part VI: Extracting River Catchments**, it's a detailed step-by-step guide based on spatial analyst hydrology tools.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.